# Connect to the Host Machine from WSL2

Tags: networking, wsl2

My LAN is configured with 192.168.31.X DNS.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL2 on Windows 10.

I am trying, from withing WSL to connect to a port on the Host machine. I figured `127.0.0.1` wouldn't work, so I tried using the LAN IP, being `192.168.31.41` in this case, however:

```
curl 192.168.31.41:8081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.31.41 port 8081: No route to host
```

What do I need to do to be able to connect to that port on the host machine from within WSL?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking

Comment: @essjae Using the `/etc/resolv.conf` nameserver worked as expected, thanks :)